Design a Ćuk converter architecture for converting 12V to a variable output ranging from 0V to -10V
I did a research about the best architecture for DC-DC convertors for having the minimum output ripple and then I noticed I should use Ćuk architecture. So for example the following controller can support Ćuk architecture:
LM2611
LT1070
But since I'm a beginner in designing Ćuk converter I'm looking for a reference design approach, would you please let me know how should I proceed in this case is there a reference design approach? (software, PDF)
Design parameters:
12V to a variable output ranging from 0V to -10V (1.5A).
Ripple less than 0.5mV

500 uV ripple would be possible with enough filters, but an adjustable LDO after some inverting DC-DC topology of choice seems appealing. Do you have high demands on step response? How fast can the adjustment be?

@winny then I will consider using LDO as well. regarding step response at this stage of this project I don not know muxh this is important, so lets say it should be in a reasonable range.

The more filters you will have, the slower the system will respond to changes in requested voltage and you will have a harder time with step response. An linear post regulator will shine in every aspect of this. You need to define values for your needs on what I mentioned to tell what route is best for you. If you production volumes are low and you can live with some dissipation, I would look into linear post regulation first.

Beware, Ćuk converters are not as simple to make work as you might think. The magnetic design necessary if you want to do the ultra-low-ripple integrated-magnetics variant is not trivial.

Is "DC-DB convertors" in the question a typo which should be "DC-DC convertors", or does it have a special meaning for Ćuk converters?

@Chester Gillon thanks, fixed

If the input is "12V" from a battery it can go quite a bit higher when fully charged. Max 14V for LM2611 would be too low in this case. If it's a 12V power supply it can be more accurate.
